# Issue while creating a JSON script in JSR223Listener

Tags: json, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have created a JSON script in JSR233 listener.
I  Created this JSon scripts for posting some data into a DB and getting following error message:

```
2017-11-07 23:03:14,096 INFO o.a.j.v.JSR223Listener: ExceptionKPI :groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.setEntity() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.json.JsonBuilder) values:.

Please find below code
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
import groovy.json.*
def jsonBuilder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
jsonBuilder {
     vars.get("testId")
     sampleResult.getSampleLabel()
    applicationName vars.get("applicationName")
    conversationId vars.get("ID")
    size sampleResult.getBytesAsLong()
    status Status
    messages FileServer.getFileServer().getScriptName()
    executionTimestamp System.currentTimeMillis()
    timeTaken sampleResult.getTime()
}
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument("",jsonBuilder.toPrettyString(),"")
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)

log.info("JASON OutPUT-----"+JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(jsonBuilder)))
            // Set Request URL
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("${URL}");

    //      StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            request.addHeader("content-type", "`enter code here`application/json");
            //request.setEntity(jsonBuilder);
            request.setEntity(jsonBuilder.toPrettyString());
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            log.info("HttpResponse response---------------------------------------------------------:" +response);
```

Comment: Please add your relevant code

Comment: Added the code as u requested

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the line:

```
setEntity(jsonBuilder)
```

to

```
setEntity(jsonBuilder.toPrettyString())
```

References:

- [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)
- [HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase.html#setEntity(org.apache.http.HttpEntity))
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing converting to Entity object as `StringEntity`

```
 setEntity( new StringEntity(jsonBuilder.toPrettyString()))
```